# Javascript Blob upload is corrupted

Tags: javascript, blob

So I have this code that modifies an image file and then converts it to a new image.

the new image (represented by `canvas.toDataURL()` ) is working perfectly,
but the conversion to the Blob is generating corrupted images.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = e.target.result;
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        context.textAlign = 'right';
        context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        context.font = "15pt Calibri";
        context.fillText(new Date().toLocaleString(), this.width - 30, this.height - 30);

        var blb = new Blob( [canvas.toDataURL()],  {type: 'image/jpeg', encoding: 'utf-8'});
        BuildingService.addFile({file: blb, filename: guid});
        category.Pictures.push({offlineFoto: canvas.toDataURL(), FileNameOnDevice: guid});
    };
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

The images are also noticable bigger then the one started with, startsize = 858KB, converted = 2.107KB

Comment: `2.107KB` seems super small to me. Anyway [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)'s result also has some header : `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0....contents..."`, you may need to strip the header first.

Comment: that's 2MB :) here `,` is the decimal mark :p

Comment: But you put `.` on your post, another point is `toDataURL` default format is `image/png`, you should give the function 1st param `image/jpeg`, and it accept 2nd param to decide the image quality, default is `1`, you may set to a smaller value to see if it reduce the image size.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say `.` is the decimal mark, and `,`is the comma. going to look into the data thingy

Comment: Ok, the use of `.` and `,` is reverse here, I know the meaning is different by places, just wanted to make a joke ;). Sorry that's all advices I can give, not familiar with Blob, dunno how to deal with it.

Comment: haha alright, and trying to make the blob work, but removing the data:... isn't working and addiing `image/jpeg` isn't working either, so don't know if I'm doing something wrong or something is not working

Comment: Just founded that canvas seems to be able to directly convert to blob, take a look at [HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob).

Comment: there isn't a default toBlob (in chrome), but adding a library toBlob is doing it's job! thanks